# python - skipping lines while using csv.dictreader

Tags: python, csv

This is follow up to this question - [2d list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036271/2d-list-in-python-accessing-through-column-names)

The answer by @Kroolik addresses my issue, but I'm stuck on another thing

consider my files is as follows

```
junk....
junk....
junk
required....
junk...
required....
junk...
```

when i read thro csv.dictreader, how do I skip the junk lines? also, I only know the first and last 'required' and the 'junk' in between. The initial 'junk' can be anything and any number of lines.

I tried the below

```
version_new = open(file_version_new, 'r')
flag = 0
for row in version_new:
   if "JID" in row:
      flag = 1  #starting of the 'required section
   if "Total text" in row:
      flag = 2  #end of required section
   if flag == 1:
      list_top_version_new.append(row.split())
   if flag == 2:
      #do something

reader = csv.DictReader(list_top_version_new)
for line in reader:
    print(line)
```

but this doesnt seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop within the loop, getting the next lines until you are at the end:

```
for row in version_new:
   if "JID" in row:
      # in required section, loop until end:
      for row in version_new:
          if "Total text" in row:
              break
          list_top_version_new.append(row)
    # Anything outside of the required section is ignored.
```

Note that `row.split()` isn't needed; `csv.DictReader` gives you a dictionary object, with the row already split out into values already.

`list_top_version_new` is also a list of dictionaries, no need to put those through `csv.DictReader()` *again*. And since you are already looping over that section of your input file, why not just *directly* in that loop do your work? So, instead of a separate loop over `list_top_version_new` at the end, replace `list_top_version_new.append(row)` with whatever work you need to do with the row:

```
for row in version_new:
   if "JID" in row:
      # in required section, loop until end:
      for row in version_new:
          if "Total text" in row:
              break
          print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks. If you have seen the post that I've [linked] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036271/2d-list-in-python-accessing-through-column-names), I'm using csv.Dictreader because, it makes the column names as keys automatically which is my main concern.