# How to ignore lines in a file starting with "##" and load the table in csv module?

Tags: python, csv

So, I have a file which has some 40 lines starting with '##'. After those lines there is a TSV table structure which I want to read using `csv.DictReader()`. 
I am trying the following code:

```
f = open(file, 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    if line.startswith('##'):
        next(line)
```

However, I am not sure how to load the data into `csv.DictReader` after ignoring these lines. Any suggestions as to how to go about this?

Comment: With such a small file, simply create a new temporary file. In the general case, probably create a custom class which inherits from `DictReader`.

Comment: This is a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189687/python-skipping-lines-while-using-csv-dictreader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an iterator, which does not realize all of the file in memory (can be a concern if the file is big)

```
def read_fn():
    path = "./text.tsv"
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('##'):
                continue
            yield line

reader = csv.DictReader(read_fn())

for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Comment: `readlines()` reads all the lines into memory. If you want to read the file a line at a time, use `for line in f:` I also suggest you use a `with` statement to ensure that the file is closed properly.

Comment: Then what you say in the first sentence of your answer is wrong and should be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create an intermediate list of lines that you then pass to `DictReader` (I am also adding a `with` statement) as this is the conventional, Pythonic way of properly handling files in case of exceptions:

```
good_lines = []
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith('##'):
            next(line)
        else:
            good_lines.append(line)

dr = csv.DictReader(good_lines)
```

Comment: You don't need to read the entire file into memory as a list of lines. Use a `yield` statement in a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) function.

Comment: All true. But it seems that this may be too advanced a topic.